# NetLogo : introducing a delay primitive?

Tags: netlogo

Is there any primitive to introduce a delay in the running of the NetLogo in between the execution of a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`wait`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#wait) primitive to do this.

```
print "hello"
wait 2
print "there"
```

will print "hello", wait 2 seconds, then print "there".

That said, I would highly recommend avoiding using `wait` (and the related `every`). There are almost always better ways to do things. One big problem with `wait` is that it makes the speed slider (at the top, under the tabs) almost useless. If you want to just slow things down, use the speed slider. If you want an agent to a wait a little bit before doing something, give it a variable that counts down to 0; when the variable hits 0, then the agent performs the action. That way, the whole simulation doesn't pause, just the agent.

Comment: Note also that under “Settings...” you can control the default rate at which your model runs when the speed slider is in its default position. It defaults to 30 frames/second (where ordinarily 1 tick = 1 frame), but you can decrease that number to get a slower default. Make sure your model is set to "Tick-based updates", not "continuous updates".